# Javascript Vimeo upload api doesn't give me real time upload-offset value

Tags: javascript, axios, vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm implementing JS Vimeo api. Everything is working great except only one thing that is essential to create my own progress bar.

According to official [docs](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#resumable-approach-step-3), i need to send head request and the server will give me `upload-offset` which represents how much data is uploaded.

And this is my code:

```js
const upload = (video, progress) => {
        const accessToken = products.vimeo.key;
        const baseUrl = 'https://api.vimeo.com';
        const headers = {};
        
        headers.Accept = 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4';
        headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
        headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: `${baseUrl}/me/videos`,
            headers: headers,
            data: {
                "upload": {
                    "approach": "tus",
                    "size": video.size
                }
            }
        }).then(response => {
            const body = response.data;
            const uploadUrl = body.upload.upload_link;
            headers['Tus-Resumable'] = '1.0.0';
            headers['Upload-Offset'] = 0;
            headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/offset+octet-stream'

            axios({
                method: 'patch',
                url: uploadUrl,
                headers: headers,
                data: video,
                onUploadProgress: (e) => {
                    axios({
                        method: 'head',
                        url: uploadUrl,
                        headers: {
                            'Tus-Resumable': '1.0.0',
                            'Accept': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4'
                        }
                    }).then(_response => {
                        const total = _response.headers['upload-length'];
                        const uploaded = _response.headers['upload-offset'];
                        const toPercent = (uploaded / total * 100).toFixed(2);
                        const progressbar = progress.find('.progressbar');

                        progressbar.css('width', toPercent);
                        console.log(`total: ${total}\tuploaded: ${uploaded}`);
                    });
                }
            }).then(_response => {
                console.log(_response);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            })
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        })
}
```

When the uploading is processing axios does make head request but the result of `upload-offset` is just 0 and it just get reached total size of file which is 100% when the processing is complete.

I printed the result of head request to see how many time the axios make head request. 14 requests made but only last request had value which is 100% and the other 13 requests had 0.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: How big is the video you are uploading there? It might just be that it is too small to even trigger any progress updates in between.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you for your quick comment! The size was between 20mb to 70mb i've tested several videos

Answer (score 1):

I believe you intend to use tus (https://tus.io/)

Have you considered using the library tus-js-client (https://github.com/tus/tus-js-client)?

I'm implementing Vimeo Upload as well, by what I've learn I believe you're probaly sending the whole video at once, that's why the offset only changes when the whole video is uploaded and the offset goes from 0 to the whole size of the video.

If you use tus, you'll be uploading chunk by chunk (easier with the library), and your offset will be changing after each chunk.
By using the library you also have a easy way to get a value for you progress indicator, here's my implementation example (I'm using typescript, js might be a little different):

```
var upload = new Upload(file, {
uploadUrl: vimeoUploadUrl,
chunkSize: 1000000,
onProgress: function (bytesUploaded: any, bytesTotal: any) {
  var percentage = (bytesUploaded / bytesTotal * 100).toFixed(2);
  console.log(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, percentage + "%");
  setProgressIndicator(Number(percentage));
},
onError: function (error) {
  console.log("Failed because: " + error)
},
onSuccess: function () {
  console.log("Download %s from %s", upload.file.name, upload.url)
}
```

})

They give great examples here on how to use it: (https://github.com/tus/tus-js-client/blob/master/docs/usage.md)

They have a section talking about Vimeo Upload specifically.